# How can I change the menu item (register) > (unregistered) once registered and back to (register) when (unregistered) is pressed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not sure on how the onPrepareOptionMenu can be used here.

```
//about and register
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case (R.id.register):
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(p1751534.this, RegisterForm.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case (R.id.about):
                intent = new Intent(p1751534.this, About.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

any help will be appreciated !

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it. Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.register);
    if (isRegister) {
        item.setTitle("UnRegister");
    } else {
       item.setTitle("Register");
    }
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and call this from your activity or fragment

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: what if my (isRegister) is in another layout/activity ? what do i put in that if(statement) ?

Comment: `IsRegister` ist the flag which indicates that the user is register or not. It is boolean.

Comment: it is giving me red error. do i have to declare in my main_activity ?

Comment: You have to create a variable. which you have to create in activity for fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two layouts for your menu depending isRegister or not:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(isRegister){
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.unregister, menu);
    }else{
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```